# How to delete data in MySQL with date range

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database. I wanted to delete all unverified users from the beginning until a specific date (May 31,2019). I have a column for `date_created` (datetime in MySQL). How can I do it? I don't want to do it manually or one by one.

Comment: What's the problem? Just use a `WHERE` clause that specifies the criteria for deleting.

Comment: Developing a delete query. **1)** Write a Select query that returns the right result set **2)** Change SELECT into DELETE

Answer (score 1):

Dates are an ordinal data type. You can use a `<` operator:

```
DELETE 
FROM   mytable
WHERE  date_created < STR_TO_DATE('2019-05-01', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: Str to date does nothing here